# Custom draw dropdown panel outside Control bounds

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+, gdi

I seem to have picked up an "unclear what I'm asking" vote. I want to custom draw a combo box style control. The pop open section needs to draw outside the bounds of the control itself. I cannot use combo box - think something similar to the gallery control in the Word ribbon.

I have thought of 2 approaches:

- Passing the pop open panel back up to the form to render.
- Using a borderless, frameless Form or NativeWindow.

The latter also allows the drop down to escape the bounds of the window, which may be of use, but is not absolutely essential.

Are there any other approaches to this, and which do you think is best?

Thanks.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm writing a winforms based custom draw UI library for a small project. All is largely going well, but I have a slight structural issue with drop downs leaving the bounds of the `Graphics` object.

Most of the controls are being done with pure custom draw and redraw event model but the overall interface is being laid out using winforms `Dock`, `Width`, `Height` etc.

I've added a dropdown, but obviously when the bounds of the drop down section of it exceed the bounds of the graphics object for the layout `Panel`, it is cut off.

(I had expected to find something similar to this on SO already, but haven't managed.)

I've worked around this by having the form control the drawing of the drop down overlay, but what with the custom mouse handler and everything else, the form is starting to feel rather overburdened.

I have tried to store references to `Graphics` objects but found that using them outside of `OnPaint` being raised is.. temperamental.

Simplified code example of current model follows. This code doesn't run in any useful way alone, but shows the approach used to display the overlays.

```
public interface IDropDownOverlay
{
    DropDown DropDown { get; }

    /// <summary>can only link to a single form at once - not a problem.</summary>
    DropDownDrawForm Form { get; set; }

    void MouseUpdate(MouseEventArgs e);

    void Render(Graphics gfx);

    void Show();
}

public class DropDown
{
    private DropDownOverlay overlay;
}

public class DropDownDrawForm : Form
{
    /* lots of other things... */

    private List<IDropDownOverlay> overlays;

    public void HideOverlay(IDropDownOverlay overlay)
    {
        if (this.overlays.Contains(overlay))
        {
            this.overlays.Remove(overlay);
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void ShowOverlay(IDropDownOverlay overlay)
    {
        if (!this.overlays.Contains(overlay))
        {
            overlay.Form = this;
            this.overlays.Add(overlay);
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        foreach (IDropDownOverlay overlay in this.overlays)
        {
            overlay.Render(e.Graphics);
        }
    }

    private void MouseUpdate(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (IDropDownOverlay overlay in this.overlays)
        {
            overlay.MouseUpdate(e);
        }
    }
}

public class DropDownOverlay : IDropDownOverlay
{
    public DropDown DropDown { get; }

    public DropDownDrawForm Form { get; set; }

    public void Hide()
    {
        this.Form.HideOverlay(this);
    }

    public void MouseUpdate(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Informs the form to redraw the area of the control.

        if (stateChanged)
        {
            this.Invalidate(); // (method to invalidate just this area)
        }
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        this.Form.ShowOverlay(this);
    }

    public void Render(Graphics gfx)
    {
    }
}
```

Obviously there are lots of bits missing from this, but it should show the approach I'm using at least.

Any suggestions to prevent me having to pass this back and forth between the form?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**

Just to be absolutely clear, the problem is drawing the "popup" section of the dropdown not the dropdown itself. (ComboBox used here to demonstrate)

[image: DropDown Control Areas]

I've also since remembered that a small window forces a ComboBox outside the bounds of the *window*.

[image: ComboBox outside window bounds]

The drop shadow on it looks suspiciously like `CS_DROPSHADOW` from `CreateParams` to me - could I use a `NativeWindow` subclass to handle this instead?

Comment: Hard to guess why you see anything at all.  A Graphics object is strongly associated with a specific window and has its own active clipping region that excludes the option of drawing into another window.  I supposed you need to call Invalidate() instead to trigger the "overlay" OnPaint method.

Comment: There's one in the MouseUpdate (albeit commented out) - basically it triggers the invalidation when the state changes in the overlay, for example when you mouse over an item within it. There should also be one in the Show and Hide methods which I seem to have missed in this example - I'll update the question to add those now.

Comment: `I'm writing a winforms based custom draw UI library for a small project` - looks like you're largely losing your time. Use WPF instead. winforms doesn't support customization.

Comment: That would often be sensible enough, but in this case WPF (or more specifically using XAML markup) doesn't suit the requirement terribly well for this project. Just to be clear *the above methodology works*. I'm just trying to see if there's a better way of dealing with drawing outside the panels clip without using the form to handle it.

Comment: If you want to custom-draw everything, then really, just custom-draw _everything_. Don't use Winforms for layout; build your own layout engine too. Maybe even just use Direct2D for rendering at that point. Otherwise, I recommend leveraging the framework and using real controls where the framework offers a control for the desired purpose. Note that with enough work, you can still customize the individual controls (i.e. subclass the native window class); but as real controls, with their own window, you won't have clipping issues. You could even write your own `Control` subclass for the purpose.

Comment: That's exactly it, I'm NOT custom drawing everything. In this particular project I am using (extended) WinForms controls. Just not this control. Also just to be doubly clear, the above is to display the popup area of the dropdown, not the dropdown itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've settled on the second of the options, which is using a second Form to display the dropdown panel. I've used an extended Form class rather than NativeWindow. Just thought I should share the results in case anyone else is attempting the same thing and finds this.

When the dropdown is selected, I set up the form using `PointToScreen` to get the coordinates. It also has the following properties set:

```
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.ControlBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Just to ensure it doesn't show up anywhere. I also add the following event handler:

```
            this.LostFocus += delegate
            {
                this.dropdown.BlockReopen(200);
                this.dropdown.Close();
            };
```

This means that it closes as soon as focus is lost, and also calls a method to block the dropdown from re-opening for 200 milliseconds. This I'm not entirely happy with, but solves so many issues in one it'll probably stay for a while. I'm also adding a drop shadow by overriding CreateParams:

```
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
                createParams.ClassStyle |= Win32Message.CS_DROPSHADOW;
                return createParams;
            }
        }
```

The end result in my quick testbed application:

[image: Ribbon Dropdown Prototype]

By approaching it in this way, I can make the dropdown escape the bounds of the window as well:

[image: Ribbon Dropdown Prototype]

My only issue now - the window frame loses focus when you open each one, which is a little jarring. I can get around that by overriding `ShowWithoutActivation` to return true, but then the `LostFocus` handler doesn't work.

More of an annoyance now, but any suggestions for fixing that very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this the other day because I came across the same situation but I've chosen to approach it differently and perhaps a better solution for a complicated situation.  In the figure below there is a SplitContainer inside of TestingForm.  In the right panel (background orange) there are two controls, one a TextBox and the other is a Panel (background color aquamarine).  Inside the aquamarine panel is a docked second split panel control containing a Label in the left side and my "CJL_PanelCtrl" in the right side.  Obviously clicking the arrow will open the control "down" overlapping any other controls.

My solution was to create a panel and place it in the parent control change where it not be bounded.  In this example that would be the right panel (orange panel) of the 1st SplitContainer.  In this case if the 1st SplitContiner was to be reisized it would move the location of the panel correctly.

[image]

Note that panel is drawing in its parent color which is orange.  The following code then accomplishes this.

The CJL_DropPanelCtrl has within it two controls, a button _btn where the image is changed depending on the state and a TextBox, _TB

```
public partial class CJL_DropPanelCtrl : UserControl
{
    internal bool IsDropped { get; set; }       // true if the panel is visible

    internal Panel DropPanel { get; private set; }  // the panel make the public set to set your own panel as needed


    /// <summary>
    /// The Control where the DropPanel will be in the Z-order chain
    /// </summary>
    internal Control PanelParent
    { get { return DropPanel.Parent; }
      set 
        {   
          DropPanel.Parent = value;
          SetLocation();
        }
    }

    public CJL_DropPanelCtrl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsDropped = false;

        DropPanel = new Panel();
        DropPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        DropPanel.Height = 100;
        DropPanel.Visible = false;  
    }

    private void OnBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsDropped = !IsDropped;
        _btn.Image = IsDropped ? Properties.Resources.DnPointer : Properties.Resources.RtPointer;
        DropPanel.Visible = IsDropped;
        DropPanel.BringToFront();   
    }

    internal void SetLocation()
    {
        // here we go up the chain of controls to determine where the location of the panel is
        // to be placed.
        Control c = _TB;
        Point offset = new Point(1, _TB.Height+2);
        while (c != DropPanel.Parent)
        {
            offset.X += c.Location.X;
            offset.Y += c.Location.Y;
            c = c.Parent;
        }
        DropPanel.Location = offset;


    }

    private void OnTBSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropPanel.Width = _TB.Width;
    }

}
```

In my TestingForm code looks like this.  Note that I set the PanelParent property and added an EventHandler for the 2nd SplitContainer splitter moving.

```
public partial class TestingForm : Form
{

    public TestingForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cjL_DropPanelCtrl1.PanelParent = splitContainer1.Panel2;
    }

    private void OnSplitter2Moved(object sender, SplitterEventArgs e)
    {
        cjL_DropPanelCtrl1.SetLocation();
    }

}
```

The only other thing to note is that I added an event Handler to the SizeChanged Event for the TextBox of the CJL_DropPanelCtrl, that way if (as is the case in my test) the control is anchored to left and right it will resize the panel correctly.

Cheers

Comment: My main problem here was delegating GDI rendering up to the parent control, but that aside, I ran into issues when using a panel with the drop down being hidden when at the bottom of the window. You can make that case drop up instead, but then very small bounds still cause problems. One of the things I found was absolutely required was to be able to escape the bounds of the parent control. Automatically closing without making a change when you click away is also problematic with a panel, especially when nesting. Just things to possibly consider when picking and testing a solution.

Comment: Yes, all of what you mention were identical problems I had, which is why I provided the solution above.  There is always a top form, which could be the main application form.  All that you have to do is to put the panel on the under the controls list of the control (or Form as case may be) and set it to "BringToFront".  Next you need the relationship between the new drop down control  you are creating and its panel, which no longer resides under the new control, controls list.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not explaining very well, or missing something, but I don't really see how it solves any of the problems - this is a basic version OF 'the problem'! Moving the panel only works when the parent is large enough to hold it, something which for me isn't always the case. That's why I had to allow the dropdown to escape the parent form bounds as needed, hence the form approach. Clicking away to close the drop down also doesn't seem to be covered. At any rate, the main problem I had was getting that working while delegating the GDI render events back to the dropdown.

Comment: With the solution I provide the parent is can be (but does not have to be) outside of the dropdown control parent.  In fact the parent can be the main form for your window, which in your case is exactly what you want.  I did not ad the "Lost Focus" but you can simply handle that the way your are doing it now.  (When the control of the panel loses focus the drop panel is removed from the "parents" control list. (again in your case this would be the control list of the main application form).  In my case my drop panel has 3 UI controls and 3 labels.  I'm not saying my is better, only different.

Comment: The problem was delegating the GDI rendering and mouse handlers, not putting a panel on a form - I just think we're talking about two completely different things here. I'm glad your solution works for what you need though, hopefully people arriving here will find what they're looking for on one or the other of these examples.

Comment: Mouse handling and GUI rendering are the beauty of what I suggested.  All are handled perfectly by .Net in the same way as if the panel for the drop down control were actually a sub control of the drop down.  The only difference is that it is not limited by the owner controls bounds, which if I'm not mistake was your original problem.

Comment: I'm not using .NETs default mouse handling or GUI rendering. The problem with the bounds was entirely a class structure problem relating to retaining or sharing the Graphics context handle so that GDI events can be invoked from one side to the other - our approaches are two unrelated solutions to two unrelated problems. Again though, anyone who arrives here may find either one of them useful depending on what they are trying to achieve.