# Windows forms. Draw a control over panel border

Tags: c#, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I've been searching for quite a while but can't seem to find exactly what I need. I have a custom button (Click on the button to show a treeview underneath the button), everything works great, but if I put the button in a panel (Panel is the parent of the custom button, and the button is the parent of the treeview) and I click the button, the panel border cuts off the treeview control.

I understand I can change the parent of the control and it will fix the problem. However, I would like the control to act like a normal combobox where the dropdown will render (paint, display) over the border of the panel.

This is what I need to happen

[image: This is what I need to happen]

This is what is happening with my treeview

[image: This is what is happening with my treeview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand I can change the parent of the control and it will fix the problem. However

Actually it would not fix it either. The form would still cut the exceeding areas.

> I would like the control to act like a normal combobox

Even the normal `ComboBox` [creates](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/8b918a8f476b7e5742e719aa7a9bb0debcb1590c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/ComboBox.cs#L3655) a new [native window](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/8b918a8f476b7e5742e719aa7a9bb0debcb1590c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/ComboBox.ComboBoxChildNativeWindow.cs#L15) for the drop-down elements that is not parented into owner's parent control. This is somewhat similar to `ToolTip` and [context]menu windows. And also note that the drop-down window is not actually anchored to the owner control, meaning, it cannot be dragged with the 'parent' form: it is [destroyed](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/8b918a8f476b7e5742e719aa7a9bb0debcb1590c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/ComboBox.cs#L3226) as soon as it loses focus, eg. when you click the title bar of the form.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This helped me to understand the problem and search more accurately for a solution and came across this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142305/custom-draw-dropdown-panel-outside-control-bounds